# Matching two columns from Pandas Dataframe but the order matters

Tags: python, pandas

I have two `DataFrames`

**df_1**:

```
idx A X
0   1 A
1   2 B
2   3 C
3   4 D
4   1 E
5   2 F
```

and
**df_2**:

```
idx B Y 
0   1 H
1   2 I
2   4 J
3   2 K
4   3 L
5   1 M
```

my goal is get the following:
**df_result**:

```
idx A X B Y
0   1 A 1 H
1   2 B 2 I
2   4 D 4 J
3   2 F 2 K
```

I am trying to match both `A` and `B` columns, based on on the column `B`from **df_2**.

Columns `A` and `B` repeat their content after getting to 4. The order matters here and because of that the row from **df_1** with `idx = 4` does not match the one from **df_2** with `idx = 5`.

I was trying to use:

`matching = list(set(df_1["A"]) & set(df_2["B"]))`

and then

```
df1_filt = df_1[df_1['A'].isin(matching)]
df2_filt = df_2[df_2['B'].isin(matching)]
```

But this does not take the order into consideration.

I am looking for a solution without many for loops.

**Edit**:

`df_result = pd.merge_asof(left=df_1, right=df_2, left_on='idx', right_on='idx', left_by='A', right_by='B', direction='backward', tolerance=2).dropna().drop(labels='idx', axis='columns').reset_index(drop=True)`

Gets me what I want.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Is it a match between both index and column A/B? Why isn't the second occurrence of A/B == 1 considered a match (with X=E and Y=M)?

Comment: I will try to make it more clear, I will edit the question

Comment: You can achieve the result with full outer join

Answer (score 0):

IIUC this should work:

```
df_result = df_1.merge(df_2,
            left_on=['idx', 'A'], right_on=['idx', 'B'])
```

Comment: You don't need to reset index, you can just pass the index name as if it's a column name.

Comment: This does not give the whole df_result as intended, it only outputs the first two rows.